# Indent an unordered list without indenting the box model

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I would like to display a simple, nested, indented, unordered list with borders between each list item.

I'm looking for an solution to indent the content of the `<li>` without indenting the whole element. Actually my borders are also intended.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kcRfT/

One possible solution is, to take the indent (left-padding) from the `<li>` nodes and use text-indent instead (as explained in the jsfiddle above).

Is there another, more beautiful solution for this issue? Any ideas?

Greetings Neil

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try by playing with negative margins on the `li`

http://jsfiddle.net/5yV3P/1/

Comment: Thanks Kurt for your answer. That's an interesting approach. Your example does not work. This approach results imho in the same behaviour as my example (Defining each indent level by hand). Right?

Comment: You could try using the CSS content attribute on each list item to prepend some padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/5yV3P/2/